# How can I do to change the first element of an array using useState?

Tags: reactjs

here is my code :

```
const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([0, 0])
```

And I would like to change only the first element to get `myArray = [3, 0]`

How can I do to do that ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

You can do in this way. First copy the state then do modification and set it again

```
const handleChange = () => {
  let copyState = [...myArray]
  copyState[0] = 3
  setMyArray(copyState)
}
```

Comment: There is also a one liner ```setMyArray(array => [3, ...array.slice(1, array.length)])```

Answer (score 0):

You can call setMyArray method passing a function as argument.
The function destructures the myArray into el1 and el2 and recreates a new array where the first element is equal to 3:

```js
setMyArray((myArray) => {
  const [el1, el2] = myArray;
  
  return [3, el2]
});
```

or simplified

```js
setMyArray(([el1, el2]) => [3, el2]);
```